# The use of "over" in the following sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning

> He was despondent over the breakup of his marriage.

You could say

A. He was despondent regarding/concerning the breakup of his marriage

B. He was despondent because of/due to/as a result of the breakup of his marriage.

1. There is no difference in the meaning whether "because of" or "concerning" is used here. Am I right?
2. "Over" could mean any one of "A & B" . Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You normally use the prepositions over or about after despondent. Some people also use "at".

Although the use of "because, due to, and as a result of" with despondent conveys the same sense as about/over and seems correct grammatically, they are not usually used.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest preposition after despondent is about (BrE). AmE prefers over.
Your variants are all possible, but they are longer and normally the shortest way to express an idea is preferred.

Comment: So IIUC, that's a Yes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a preposition.

There's actually a few different prepositions that would work there, with slightly different shades of meaning.  I'll provide some examples with a shorter sentence.

> She was upset **at** her husband

^ Husband did something to upset her, and maybe she is angry at him.  For example he said something rude in front of dinner guests.

> She was upset **over** her husband

^ Something was happening to her husband, or her husband was involved in some situation which upset her.  For example, he is sick.

> She was upset **because of** her husband

Husband did something that directly upset her.  Perhaps he was pushing her buttons that morning.

> She was upset **with** her husband

^ She is definitely angry at him. Maybe he forgot her anniversary.

> She was upset **about** her husband

^ She is definitely not angry at him.  Something happened *to* her husband that is upsetting.  Maybe he is being targeted in an upsetting lawsuit.